# Django ORM Nested query set counts isse

Tags: django, orm, connection

I am using Django ORM nested queries.

Reference found here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in

But when i count `connection.queries` its say 122, i am so surprised if i am hitting db for 122 times?

### Code

```
 from django.db import connection

    connection.queries = []
    started_pros = Log.objects.filter(state="Chemist Working").values_list('product__id', flat=True).distinct()
    pro = Products.objects.exclude(id__in=started_pros)
    print [r.id for r in pro]
    len(connection.queries) #122
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change in your query

```
pro = list(Products.objects.exclude(id__in=started_pros).values_list('id', flat=True))
```

or

```
pro = list(Products.objects.exclude(id__in=started_pros))
```

Because iterating a queryset make another query